# IDEA: Unnecessary module dependency inspection false positive

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

In my IDEA project, I have 2 modules, where classes from module **A** extend those from module **B**.

*Unnecessary module dependency* inspection says:

"Dependency from module 'A' on module 'B' could be removed when complementary scope to 'Module 'A'' also does not contain references on module 'B'".

What does *complementary scope* mean and why the dependency on **B** is considered unnecessary?